# Does amazon have same API as google license for android apps?

Tags: android, licensing, amazon-appstore

My question is very straight-forward but I could not find it on Amazon developer page. Could someone please help me with this? I would like to know if I need to do anything to license the paid app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After couple of days finding, I known Amazon handle this for us. (And In-app purchase is in beta phase)